# Missing column on power bi

Tags: mongodb, csv, powerbi, powerquery

I exported a collection in mongo db as a csv file and then imported that csv into power bi…all fields imported except one . Even after manually adding it in mongodb before exporting as csv, the column showed blank when I loaded it into power query. The Column shows channels used such as mobile app, website etc…What can be the issue and how can I fix it.

I tried manually adding the column and it showed blank on power bi.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle check mark to accept answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

Look at code for part that says

```
,columns =16,
```

and remove that

Answer (score 0):

As column # in all csv should be same . While using folder connector to keep all dataset into model power query take first csv file and based of it analyze schema and column# .If let suppose any csv have more column with it will not show there . So you need two checklist

1. Check all csv have similar schema with same number of column
2. Second check the parameter of columns

I hope this will help you